# Adding or Removing a host key in Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions

How we can add/remove a host key in Azure Function App? Can we do it via code or it is possible only via Azure portal?

Comment: Check out this post: https://www.markheath.net/post/managing-azure-function-keys. HTH.

Comment: But, if I created multiple host keys and i want to choose particular host key. Is it possible via Azure portal?

Answer (score 0):

You can create/delete / update or retrieve a bunch of keys or a specific key using the `Key Management API`. As mentioned by @Gaurav in the comment, the blog has a method to do it from `PowerShell`.

But in case if you are not familiar with PowerShell, you can consume the API's from here directly in whatever language you prefer.

[Key Management API](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Key-management-API)

Comment: I call this (https://<functionappname>.azurewebsites.net/admin/functions/{function-name}/keys )endpoint to get function keys  via Postman. but I am getting 404 not found error.

Comment: @RakeshKumar you need to pass Bearer Token credentials